# Is it possible that Socket.Send block the code and take forever to finish?

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, tcp, asyncsocket

I got this Socket.Send code, my protocol is tcp.

```
byte[] commandBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(command);
int iBytesSent = socket.Send(commandBytes, commandBytes.Length, SocketFlags.None);
Debug.WriteLine("SEND: " + command);
```

I have over 10,000 commands to send, each command is around 100 characters.
I call the `Socket.Send` in a foreach loop for 10,000 commands.

I notified that the Socket.Send code blocks the current thread and takes forever to finish. (The debug.WriteLine stop printing to output console.)

**So my question:**

Is it possible that because I send the commands too fast and this cause the stream full?

So it have to wait until the stream is available and continue to send?

I also notified that there is a moment the Socket.Send block the code for 5-10 seconds, and then continue.
But as time passed, 5-10 seconds becomes 20-30 and then it takes forever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible for `Send` to block, although in most code you rarely see it. If you don't want to tie up a thread, you could use async socket IO (`BeginSend`/`EndSend`, or `SendAsync`). However, this doesn't make it any *faster* - it just means that you aren't blocking a thread while the socket is busy. Are you perhaps out-pacing the other end of this connection?

Comment: I do not control the other end of this connection. The order end is IQFeed, a financial quote data provider. My application just send command to IQFeed and receive the quotes. My problem is something related to big data. e.g. There can be  hundreds millions of records that I can receive, and sometime I have to send over 20,000 or command.

Comment: @VuNguyen that doesn't mean you need to send everything at once - nor is it beneficial to do so. You say you are also receiving: perhaps throttle the number of pending requests to a sane number - that way you won't be out-pacing the other end.

Comment: @VuNguyen or, as already stated: use async IO; then it will back off automatically

Comment: I tried with this: after send a command, I call Thread.Sleep(1000) and it still works until now (~30 minutes), which meant that the Thread/Connection/Socket have 1 second to process things. I don't know what to name it (Thread/Connection/Socket)?

Comment: Hello again, I tried to use SendAsync, but it seems that after hundreds of sent commands, it cannot send anymore. I know this because in SendAsyncEventArgs' completed event, I print out a debug string. After hundreds of sent commands, it stopped printing, even I have more than 10,000 commands.

Comment: @VuNguyen again; it isn't that it isn't sending: it is that it **isn't complete**. The fundamental issue here is that the remote server is too slow. There is nothing fundamentally broken in sockets here - I have sockets that remain open for days, sending constantly. The problem is almost certainly the service you are connecting to **isn't processing the backlog**. If the remote endpoint refuses to accept new packets, and your buffers are all full, then **you need to wait**.

Comment: Ok, thanks for a lot of information. Last question, if I need to wait, how long do I have to wait? And there is a change that while I'm waiting, the server closes/disconnects/etc. In that case, what will I get?